# Where one can find historical and\or actual europe shore height data?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

So remember Venice floods? I wonder where one can find a record on historical and\or actual Europe shore height data (especially for north Europe)?

Comment: shore height related to which location? 
https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/7qso6a/til_the_two_halves_of_the_high_rhine_bridge/